# HP Rapid Deployment - Change Data Store Path

Tags: deployment, hp, configuration-management

I am running HP Rapid Deployment (Altiris eXpress Deployment Server 6.9 - Build 164) on an inherited Windows Server 2003 SP2. I need to change the Data Store Path as the default is pointing to the C: drive and there is not enough space there. I would like to set it to the D: drive where there is plenty of space.
Reading the documentation:

Data store path:
Specifies the path to stored packages and files and other DS functions (such as license verification). The default path is C:\Program files\Altiris\express\Deployment Server.
Note:
Do not use this setting to change the path to the Deployment Share. Modifying this setting does not automatically allow you to use another shared directory other than the express share. To change the Deployment Share shared directory, run a Custom install to establish another location for the Deployment Share.

Is there any other way I can change the path as I do not have the install media?

Answer (score 0):

managed to find the answer:
https://kb.altiris.com/display/1/kb/articleContent.asp?aid=33382&n=1&s=&link=